# Are Lipschitz continuity and strongly convexity two (loosely speaking) opposite concepts?

Tags: convex-analysis, lipschitz-functions

Intuitively, if a differentiable function is $k$-Lipschitz continuous, it should not vary a lot. On the other hand, if a function is strongly convex, it my vary a lot. Am I correct? Is there any deeper relationship between these two concepts?

Comment: I'm no expert, but there seems to be something to what you're saying. A function that is globally Lipschitz cannot escape a linear envelope, since $|f(x)-f(y)|\leq C|x-y|,$ but being strongly convex means that the function has to grow at least quadratically when $|x-y|$ is large. If you're thinking of the properties as being local (as I usually do), then they are consistent, but they become inconsistent the more globally you look.

Comment: If f is strongly convex then $f'(x) \geq f'(0)+mx$ for $x>0$. Hence $f(x)=\int_0 ^x f'(t)dt \geq m\{x^{2}/2\}+f'(0)x$. On the other hand Lipschitz condition implies $f(x) \leq ax+b$ For large x we get a contradiction.

Comment: Thanks for the comments! But what do you mean by "consistent"? Lipschitz continuous also implies strongly convex (locally)?